# Pasar fecha a edad

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de SQL y no estoy muy seguro que la solución este bien, os dejo el enunciado y la solución.

15. Apellidos, Nombre, edad y número de hijos de los empleados que tienen más de 50 años y tienen hijos. Resultado:

    ```
    SELECT NOMBRE, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, FNACIMIENTO)/12) AS EDAD, HIJOS 
    FROM N_EMPLEADOS 
    WHERE TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, FNACIMIENTO)/12) > 50 AND HIJOS > 0;
    ```

Donde tengo la duda es que si es correcta la forma de calcula la edad, FNACIMINETO es de tipo date:

```
TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, FNACIMIENTO)/12) AS EDAD
```

Comment: Es una buena forma de hacerlo, aunque ten en cuenta que - según la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm)- dependiendo la fecha que le entregues, podría no darte un entero como resultado ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El MONTHS_BETWEEN obtiene un numero decimal con la cantidad de meses y para calcular el año está el /12. Esto estaría bien porque devuelve un decimal.

Luego el TRUNC retorna un entero. Por ejemplo 12.7 años, te dejaría el 12.

Podés ver más info en:
Month_Between -> https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/datetime-functions/oracle-months_between-function.php
Trunc -> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm